# Rxjs combineLatest does returning the observable with in the suscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9, fork-join, combinelatest

I am trying to get Userid and serviceId after I need to get a call based on the userid,serviceId problem here is it's not returning the observable to the ts.

Service.ts

```
function getData():observable<any>{
   combineLatest([
      this.activeSellService.getActiveSellServiceId(),
      this.authService.getUserId(),
    ]).subscribe(([serviceId, userId]) => {
      if (serviceId&& userId) {
        const Url =
          'users/' +
          `${userId}` +
          '/services/' +
          `${serviceId}` +
          '?value=test
        return this.http.get<any>(this.endPoint.getUrl(encodeURI(Url)));
      }
    })
}
```

Component.ts:

```
 this.service.getData().subscribe(data=>{console.log(data));
```

Even its not print the data in the console because the service is not returning observable. kindly help me out with this problem. else can we go with different solutions in rxjs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this out

```
function getData():observable<any>{
   return combineLatest(
      this.activeSellService.getActiveSellServiceId(),
      this.authService.getUserId(),
    ).pipe(mergeMap([serviceId, userId]) => {
      if (serviceId && userId) {
        const Url =
          'users/' +
          `${userId}` +
          '/services/' +
          `${serviceId}` +
          '?value=test
        return this.http.get<any>(this.endPoint.getUrl(encodeURI(Url)));
      }
    })
}
```

note on the arguments of combinelatest and there is not subscription in getData

eg in stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-combinelatest-hjyfa6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to use a [higher order mapping operator](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) like [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/switchMap) to map from one observable to another. Moreover, the `subscribe()` function takes only callbacks and returns the [`Subscription`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscription) object that contains the subscription.

Also you aren't returning anything if the `if` condition fails. You could return an observable like RxJS constant [`NEVER`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/NEVER) to not emit anything or [`of(null)`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) to emit `null`.

Furthermore

1. `observable<any>` must be `Observable<any>`
2. You aren't returning from the function yet.
3. The `function` keyword isn't required in Typescript. Instead you could mention the scope identifier.
4. You're mixing string concatenation with template literals. Although there isn't syntactically wrong with it, I'd say it's better to stick with either or the other.
5. <strike>Guessing from the context of the function, I believe you wish to make the request once and be done with it. Instead of a stream of data provided by `combineLatest`. In that case you could use `forkJoin` instead. However note that `forkJoin` only emits when all it's sources complete.</strike>

Try the following

```js
import { Observable, forkJoin, NEVER, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

public getData(): Observable<any> {
  return combineLatest([
    this.activeSellService.getActiveSellServiceId(),
    this.authService.getUserId(),
  ]).pipe(
    switchMap(([serviceId, userId]) => {
      if (!!serviceId && !!userId) {
        const Url = `users/${userId}/services/${serviceId}?value=test`;
        return this.http.get<any>(this.endPoint.getUrl(encodeURI(Url)));
      } else {
        return NEVER; // <-- or `of(null)` to return `null` or whatever you wish to return
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: but it does not return any value

Comment: @FrontEndDeveloper: Like I said, `forkJoin` only returns if all the sources complete. If you wish to have a stream of data, replace it with `combineLatest` and try again.

Comment: have you seen my code its not about the completion of the two api scenario.Wants to load the component Ui in two different parent component

Comment: @FrontEndDeveloper: I've updated the code to use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin`.